In Kafka read_commited, can we get all of the messages in a transaction at once in consumer.poll?
In Kafka, I know by using read_commited, we only get already committed messages.
Does this mean when we poll messages, do we always receive entire committed messages?
Here is the example. (assuming consumer.poll batch size is big enough let's say 10k)

publisher: beginTransaction()
publisher: send 1000 messages
consumer: at this point, consumer.poll() will return nothing
publisher: commitTransaction()
consumer: consumer.poll() always returns 1000 messages? Or depending on timing or something, could it return, for example, 500 messages at first and in the next call of consumer.poll, we get the rest 500 messages?

The background of this question is publisher is sending a snapshot data at a certain time point and we don't want to be in a situation where we receive a part of messages in a transaction by single polling.
If we can archive this objective, any other Kafka feature is welcomed to use.
Also, if you could provide official document link, that'd be super helpful.
FYI, as long as we can consume all of the messages in a transaction atomically, we're okay with receiving more than one transactions in single consumer.poll()

publisher: beginTransaction()
publisher: send 1000 messages
publisher: commitTransaction()
publisher: beginTransaction()
publisher: send 1500 messages
publisher: commitTransaction()
consumer: consumer.poll() return 1000 or 2500 messages -> fine, 500 or 1500 -> not fine

I searched around in the Kafka document, but it wasn't clear to me if we can receive entire messages in a transaction by single poll. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_isolation.level
